# Difference between the methods of instantiating array

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose in one problem we have to declare an array of n size, where `1 <= n <= 1000000000`

There are two (can be more) ways to do this:

1. `int arr[1000000001];` and can work with the space as needed according to the input.
2. One can first ask user the size of array and then instantiate the array:

   cin>>n;
   int arr[n];

I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of both the methods.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in two methods is that:

First method is standard compliant while the second is non standard compliant. Variable length arrays are not allowed by the C++ standard.They are supported by compilers as extensions but the usage is not portable in strict sense.

The risk with first method is that, one may run out of stack space or wasting up memory eventhough it is not required. The best solution in this case is to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Which one would be faster between them?
Vectors are not as fast as arrays so one cannot go with that option always.

Comment: @user3159685 Did you really benchmark your program to see if the type of array causes the bottleneck? If no, then don't worry about it (anyway, `vector::operator[]` will be optimized to a single pointer arithmetic + load or store instruction using any modern, decent compiler and stdlib implementation). If, however, this **actually** is the bottleneck, then you can always go with `operator new`.